# Redirection through .htaccess not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a domain which has sub-domains (add-on). I am trying to redirect users from main (old) domain to one of sub-domains (new).

First I tried to redirect everything that user types within the OLD domain except one page and one directory... Now this EXCEPT feature is going out of control. I have been trying and implementing all possible options but some it gives an error and stops redirection.

Here are the lines from .htaccess file which I am trying:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} oldrootdomain.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^/view_card.php(.*)$ http://newsubdomain.com/view_card.php$1
RewriteRule ^/m/(.*)$ http://oldrootdomain.com/m/$1

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsubdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You should give details of the error you see. Does it help if you add a `[L]` flag after the first two rules? And you need to include the `RewriteCond` again for the `/m/` directory. You can have only one `RewriteRule` per `RewriteCond`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you run into an inifinite loop.
You DON'T want to redirect for those exception. So try some additional `RewriteCond`s

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} oldrootdomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !view_card.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !m/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !m$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsubdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Also you seem to have not understood the `RewriteCond`/`RewriteRule` thing entirely

Any successive *stream* of `RewriteCond`s does **only** affect the **directly following** `RewriteRule`

Comment: @sana Do the others work? I made an edit to my code to take care of example.com/m